# Adding a class when images are loading

Tags: jquery

The following code is not working. No class gets added to the images. Any idea why? Thanks for any suggestions.

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
 var starting_pics = ["AN.gif", "CN.gif", "EN.gif", "GN.gif"];    
 var i = 0;    
 for (i = 0; i < starting_pics.length; i++) {    
 $("<img/>").attr("src", "images/" + starting_pics[i]).load(function () {    
 $(this).appendTo("#main");    
 $(this).addClass(".pics");     
}); 

} 

 $(".pics").click(function () {    
 alert("Whatever");    
});

}); //end ready
```

Comment: The selector `$("")` indicates that you're either manipulating something that does not exist, or that there's something missing in the code you provided.

Comment: `$("")` is for ".pics"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
    var starting_pics = ["AN.gif", "CN.gif", "EN.gif", "GN.gif"];    
    var i = 0;    
    for (i = 0; i < starting_pics.length; i++) {    
        $("<img/>").attr("src", "images/" + starting_pics[i]).load(function () {    
            $(this).appendTo("#main");    
            $(this).addClass("pics");//when adding a class there is no need to prefix `.`
        }); 

    } 

    //need to use event delegation here since the images are added dynamically
    $("#main").on('click', ".pics", function () {    
        alert("Whatever");    
    });

}); //end ready
```